# Print the first character of JSON object from rest api - angular 2

Tags: angular

I have an Angular2 form that submits on click of Submit Button. One of the fields is a "Type" field that is a drop down selection from an API loaded values. the Type Api looks like below -
Type API:

```
[
  {
    "DTypeId": "100",
    "DTypeDesc": "AB ASSISTANCE IN",
    "DCategoryCd": "BUSINESS"
  },
  {
    "DTypeId": "790",
    "DTypeDesc": "GH MANAGEMENT CONTRIB",
    "DCategoryCd": "EVITES"
  },
  {
    "DTypeId": "309",
    "DTypeDesc": "ZT TECHNOLOGY FINANCE",
    "DCategoryCd": "ZETANGLE"
  },
{
    "DTypeId": "901",
    "DTypeDesc": "IU MANAGEMENT IN",
    "DCategoryCd": "BUSINESS"
  },
  {
    "DTypeId": "445",
    "DTypeDesc": "OP ASSISTANCE CONTRIB",
    "DCategoryCd": "EVITES"
  },
  {
    "DTypeId": "789",
    "DTypeDesc": "ZT TECHNOLOGY FINANCE",
    "DCategoryCd": "ZETANGLE"
  }

]
```

1. I am trying to display the drop down field on the HTML as below-
   ( {{DCategory-DTypeDesc}}
   basically, append the first letter of the object DCategoryCd from TYPE API to the DTypeDesc object

   ```
    <select #typeRef="ngModel" class="form-control" 
     name="typeCode" [(ngModel)]="editFormModel.typeCode"
     required>
     <option *ngFor="let tytype of getTypesTyps" 
     [ngValue]="tytype.DTypeId">{{tytype.DCategoryCd}}-
     {{tytype.DTypeDesc}}</option>
     </select>
   ```

the above code results as below -

```
 BUSINESS-AB ASSISTANCE IN <br>
 EVITES-GH MANAGEMENT CONTRIB<br>
 ZETANGLE-ZT TECHNOLOGY FINANCE<br>
 BUSINESS-IU MANAGEMENT IN<br>
 EVITES-OP ASSISTANCE CONTRIB<br>
 ZETANGLE-ZT TECHNOLOGY FINANCE
```

but, I'm trying to achieve it as below -

```
     B-AB ASSISTANCE IN <br>
     E-GH MANAGEMENT CONTRIB<br>
     Z-ZT TECHNOLOGY FINANCE<br>
     B-IU MANAGEMENT IN<br>
     E-OP ASSISTANCE CONTRIB<br>
     Z-ZT TECHNOLOGY FINANCE
```

2. Second part is this form once submitted routes to a home page that has an edit button on each row of the table. On click of this edit button, comes to the edit form (similar form as add new form with above Type field as one of them). This Type field now has to pre-populate the value from home page table. I was able to achieve it for all other fields except this type field due to the appending thing going on.

Is this possible? Thank you, so much in advance. I am kind of stuck at this forever now. So any directions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you can just change the following in the option

```
  <option *ngFor="let t of value" 
  [ngValue]="t.DTypeId">{{t.DCategoryCd[0]}}- // add this 
  {{t.DTypeDesc}}</option>
```

[**working link**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-test)

Comment: {{t.DTypeId.substr(0,1)}}

Comment: @Rahul Singh answer worked perfect!! I can't thankyou enough!. How do I show this {{t.DCategoryCd[0]}}-{{t.DTypeDesc}} on the [(ngModel)] as the default selected one when navigated from home page to edit form? any inputs on that? thankyou, again!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:  {{t.DCategoryCd[0]}}-{{t.DTypeDesc}} as suggested by @Rahul Singh and also,

{{t.DTypeId.substr(0,1)}} by @Eliseo.

Either one worked for me!